# Live preview of text using javascript

Tags: javascript

I create a live preview of what ever I type in text area or text box, the preview is working fine, [my fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/msz900/aoj17225/)

HTML

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="desc" rows="10" cols="5"name="desc"></textarea> 
<div class="col-md-6 container" id="live-preview"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#desc').keyup(function(){
        $('#live-preview').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

the problem is when I type

````
``` </html><p>some text</p></html>```
````

then it will show the output

````
```<html>some text</html>```
````

the `<p>` tag is considered as paragraph in live preview but the ```` '```' ```` is not considered as `code` tag.

**What I want:**  *I want when I type `*` then the star is converted into `<em>` tag or `<I>`, same for code tag*

Comment: I can work on that but that's too much help if people are just using mobile phones to answer 

Comment: You want a Markdown parser then and then write to the innerHTML property of the element.

Comment: Then go ahead and program what you need!

Comment: @MSZ You should replace `$(this).val()` by the result of a function parsing (and transforming) the text. cf. previous commenters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many markdown modules out there in the wild (google is your best friend):

- [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it)
- [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked)
- [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js)

Here is an example using markdown-it ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/892zxyka/4/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var md = window.markdownit(); // get a markdown instance

    $('#desc').keyup(function () {
        var html = md.render($(this).val()); // parse the markdown into html
        $('#live-preview').html(html);
    });
});
```

Try this string - `` `<p></p>` *emphasize* and **bold** ``

Don't forget to add the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/4.4.0/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like the you are expecting the browser to render Markdown dynamically on keyup. Unfortunately, Markdown is a lightweight markup language with no direct usage in browsers or HTML/CSS. @Ori Drori has offered solutions to help you do this properly.

Comment: @ori Drori  Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score -2):

use css to point p as code.

http://jsfiddle.net/aoj17225/5/

```
p{
background-color:grey;
padding:10px 3px;  
 }
```